# Detectar se o site caiu

Tags: servidor

Alguém sabe como esse site faz isso ou em que linguagem ele foi feito para conseguir fazer uma aplicação com uma função parecida?

http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

Comment: Cara, **creio** que ele só faz um `ping` no site e vê se o mesmo responde, não tem mistério.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente é possível identificar se um host ou servidor está disponível realizando um `ping` através de seu `hostaname` ou `IP`.

**Um exemplo de ping que funcionou (ou seja, o host/site está de pé):**

```
Pinging prd029 [xxx.xx.xx.x] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 172.16.5.69: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=254
Reply from 172.16.5.69: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=254
Reply from 172.16.5.69: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=254
Reply from 172.16.5.69: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=254

Ping statistics for 172.16.5.69:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% los
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 20ms, Maximum = 22ms, Average = 21ms
```

**Um exemplo de ping que falhou:**

```
Pinging www.google.com [216.58.222.4] with 32 bytes of data:

Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 216.58.222.4:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

> Entretanto, é incorreto dizer que uma falha no `ping` pode
>   caracterizar uma "queda" do site/sistema. Você pode ainda ter
>   problemas de roteamento de seu `IP` até o que deseja chegar.
>
> Testei o Google, por exemplo, e não funcionou porque o problema era na minha rede.

Answer (score 3):

Eu acho que esse site deve verificar a porta 80 do site que você digita.
Se você quiser algo para controle usa o [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/), com ele é possível monitorar o status de qualquer serviço, seja banco de dados, site, ftp, email, etc.

Ele faz isso monitorando a porta do serviço, o bacana é que você pode criar alertas para te notificar se o serviço cair.

Comment: Inclusive é open-source! :)

Comment: @FellipeSoares é verdade!!! É importante ressaltar isso tb ;)